# Parameters not passing in url in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, simple-form

I am using rails 4 and rspec 2. I have a simple_form which sends an email.

```
<%= simple_form_for @student, url: create_message_pro_users_path(student_id: @student), method: :get  do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :subject, input_html: { size: 59 } %>
    <%= f.input :message, as: :text, input_html: { class: 'text_block' } %>
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Update' %>
<% end %>
```

In the test environment, this routes to the create_message action in the pro_users controller with params[:student_id] and params[:student], i.e. it works as I would expect.

In my development environment, this routes to the correct action with the params[:student], but does not have a params[:student_id], i.e. it does not work.

If I look at the browser source code, the relevant section is

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form edit_student" id="edit_student_1847" action="/pro_users/create_message?student_id=1847" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
```

What is going wrong and why is it working in my tests but not the actual browser.  My solution at present is to refactor the action into my student controller, where I can just use standard routing. However, I use BDD so it is disconcerting when the request spec passes but it does not work in the browser!

Comment: Are you creating a resource?  If so, why isn't the form `Post`ing?

Comment: I am not creating a resource, the subject and message fields are just used to send an email to the student.